# How can I use inheritance properly while still being efficient?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have some classes here:

```
class weapons
{
protected:
    int damage, armor, cost;
};

class sword : public weapons
{
public:
    // Initialization for the sword class.
    void initialize()
    {

    }
};

class shield : public weapons
{

};
```

I started working on these and I do not remember how to set the damage, armor, and cost for each inherited class. How do I do this? What is a quick way (does not have to be easy)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way of setting up variables in a class is through the constructor of their class. Derived classes should use initializer list to set variables in their base classes.

```
class weapon {
protected:
    int damage, armor, cost;
    weapon(int d, int a, int c) : damage(d), armor(a), cost(c) {}
};

class sword : public weapon {
private:
    int weight;
public:
    sword(int d, int a, int c, int w) : weapon(d, a, c), weight(w) {}
};
```

Alternatively, if the subclass controls the values in the base (i.e. the user does not pass `damage`, `armor`, or `cost` you can do this:

```
sword(int w) : weapon(30, 5, 120), weight(w) {}
```

The compiler will optimize this code to inline things properly, so you should not worry about the performance suffering from adding an extra layer of constructors.

Comment: That's right. I thought I was missing something. Thanks. One other question about that. Do I need a `{}` or can I just use `;`?

Comment: @VinylScratch C++ syntax requires a pair of braces around bodies of methods and constructors, so you cannot use a free-standing no-op "semicolon" statement for the empty body of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Just use them in the child class. Because the properties are defined as protected in the parent, they can be accessed like normal variables in the child. Like this:

```
damage = 60;
armor = 0;
cost = 42;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class weapons
{
protected:
    int damage, armor, cost;
    weapons(int d, int a, int c): 
      damage(d), armor(a), cost(c) { }
};

class sword: public weapons {
  public:
    sword(): weapons(10, 12, 31) { }
}
class shield: public weapons {
  public:
    shield(): weapons(1, 22, 48) { }
}
```